# Memory leak when submitting form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have a hook that controls request to an endpoint and a form that makes a post when submitting and it's complaining that when submitting it's leaking memory, but I don't see where this is in the code.

**ERROR:**

[image]

**FORM**

```
const onSubmit = useCallback(
        ({ STRUCTURE_PARAMETER }: { STRUCTURE_PARAMETER: { [key: string]: string } }) => {
            return QUOTATION_SERVICES_HOOK.askForQuote({
                parameters: normalizeData(STRUCTURE_PARAMETER),
                productInfoId: STRUCTURE_FORM_HOOK.dataId || '',
                kindValue: switchMask,
            });
        },
        [STRUCTURE_FORM_HOOK.dataId, switchMask]
    );
```

**HOOK**

```
const useQuotation = () => {
    const AXIOS_HOOK = useAxiosFetch();
    const HISTORY_ROUTER_DOM_HOOK = useHistory();
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [data, setData] = useState<IQuotation[] | []>([]);
    const [queryPageInit, setQueryPageInit] = useState(1);
    const [queryPageEnd, setQueryPageEnd] = useState(0);

    const hasData = useMemo(() => data.length > 0, [data]);
    const dataLength = useMemo(() => data.length, [data]);
    const isPaginationEnd = useMemo(() => queryPageInit === queryPageEnd, [queryPageInit, queryPageEnd]);

    const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
        setIsLoading(true);

        return AXIOS_HOOK.get<unknown, IQuotation[]>(`/Quotation?_page=${queryPageInit}&_limit=3`)
            .then((quotation) => {
                setData(quotation);
                setQueryPageEnd(quotation.length); // CRIAR LÓGICA CORRETA A PARTIR DO BACKEND
                setQueryPageInit(queryPageInit + 1); // CRIAR LÓGICA CORRETA A PARTIR DO BACKEND
            })
            .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
    }, [AXIOS_HOOK, queryPageInit]);

    const askForQuote = useCallback(
        async (parameter: IAskForQuote) => {
            setIsLoading(true);
            toast.info('Aguarde, Solicitando Cotação...');

            return AXIOS_HOOK.post<unknown, IAskForQuote>(`/Quotation`, parameter)
                .then(() => HISTORY_ROUTER_DOM_HOOK.push('/stored'))
                .catch(() => toast.error('Ops, A cotação não pode ser solicitada!'))
                .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
        },
        [AXIOS_HOOK]
    );

    return {
        isLoading,
        isPaginationEnd,
        data,
        dataLength,
        hasData,
        fetchData,
        askForQuote,
    };
};

export default useQuotation;
```

I really can't see anything that could cause this leak, I'm following the documentation standards. Where is this leak actually located and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you consuming this component? React is screaming at you because you are attempting to `setState` on a component that has already unmounted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is probably here:

```
            return AXIOS_HOOK.post<unknown, IAskForQuote>(`/Quotation`, parameter)
                .then(() => HISTORY_ROUTER_DOM_HOOK.push('/stored'))
                .catch(() => toast.error('Ops, A cotação não pode ser solicitada!'))
                .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
```

You are calling history `HISTORY_ROUTER_DOM_HOOK.push('/stored')` first

Then your component unmounts probably, because route was changed and you want to render another page.

And then you call `.finally(() => setIsLoading(false));` which changes the state of the hook which was already unmounted.

Maybe you have other similar places, look for similar situations in your code.